# Automatic deployment of VNC server to remote terminals (PC's) via Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

We have several remote, unmanned terminals where I require a VNC server, as using Remote Desktop prevents others using the terminals.  Often the connection to one of these is extremely slow, and manually using Remote Desktop to perform the VNC installation is painstaking.  What I would like to do is build a package that I could copy onto the remote terminal using Remote Desktop, and then have the package executed to install and configure VNC when the terminal restarts, as they all automatically restart nightly.  The terminals are all running Windows XP.  Also, out of the many VNC variants out there, which would suit this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any special authentication requirements?  How picky are you about performance?  If you want integrated Windows authentication you would want UltraVNC.

Have you done a search for `deploy vnc`?  Depending on the version of VNC, in many cases it is as easy as copy files to the system, adding any prefs to the registry, and running the command to add the service.  If you need integrated Windows authentication, or higher video performance it gets trickier since you have to install drivers.

- http://wpkg.org/TightVNC
- http://www.waynezim.com/2009/05/how-to-deploy-vnc-using-group-policy/

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just push a single-click VNC client (check on the ultraVNC site) onto the terminals with the user login script or run a script before biz hours?

The single-click VNC client is a single pre-configured exe, less than 500kiB in size. The end-user would have to double-click on it, but it may make them feel empowered :-)

Comment: I need a VNC server on the terminals for maintenance from my office.

Comment: I'm confused. Don't worry, it's easily done :-) Why do you have to work on the actual terminals with VNC server? In my line of work, I may ask the terminal user to show their desktop to me so I can figure out what the perceived problem is, but then I ask them to logout so I can work on their desktop from a direct remote desktop session. Once I'm done, the enduser can login from their terminal again.